# Swift: subscript for array with custom type

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class, `MyClass`, and in another class I have a global variable array:

```
var myArray:[MyClass]
```

In `MyClass` I don't have any array.

Now, if I want to do this:

```
for index in 0..10 {
    self.myArray[index] = //a new object
}
```

I get an error that `MyClass` doesn't have a subscript. Any thoughts on why? Remember that `MyClass` doesn't have any arrays in it.

Some more code to show you what I mean:

```
class TheirClass {
  var myArray: [MyClass] = []  // or use an initializer

  func test() -> Void { 
     for index in 0..10 {
       self.myArray[index] = MyClass()
     }
  }
}

class MyClass {
  var prop1 = ""
  var prop2 = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling a var from another class you would have to address it like I do below:

```
class TheirClass {
    var myArray: [MyClass] = []  // or use an initializer
}

class MyClass {
    var objectArray = TheirClass().myArray  
}
```

Not sure if this is what you planned to do or not.  Let me know and I can alter the code to fit your purpose.

Comment: The problem is not with initiating the array. The problem is with accessing it's items with an index:

Comment: Gotcha, but you have to call the array from the class it comes from.  myArray does not exist in your current class unless you did what I showed already.  If you did, let me know and I will take it further.

Comment: You were correct MinnesotaSteve. When I changed the initiation way the error disappeared. So thank you for the comment, and sorry that I didn't realised it until now.

Comment: Just glad you got your code working.  So frustrating at times.

Answer (score 0):

You have `..` in the code which doesn't exist in Swift. You probably meant `...` but there is `..<` as well.

However, you have an array of size zero in your initializer, which means that you can't add values to it. You'll either have to create a new array of the right size first of all, or append to it using `myArray += [MyClass()]`.

Also note that the `-> Void` is unnecessary - if you don't have a return type, it will implicitly be a void type.